# Admin SDK generate link to access reset password page

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

In GSuite, creating a user or resetting a password gives you the option to notify the user by mail. The email contains a link where he can then set a new password.

Is there any way to reproduce that with [googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) ?

Can't find anything related to that in the reference api : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/

The response from `POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users` doesn't seem to provide any information to create that link.

Thanks

Comment: What you can do is to [update the user's resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update) and set the option `changePasswordAtNextLogin` to `true`.

Comment: For created accounts that means I need to send the user the password I chose right?@ziganotschka

Comment: You can send a temporary password with the option that the user needs to change it after logging in for the first time.

Comment: well i guess that's my only option... Thanks