# How to trigger a G Suite password reset email through Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-directory-api

I am creating G Suite user accounts programmatically through a web app powered by Google Apps Script.

The flow I am following when doing this manually is the following:

1. Create the user
2. Go through the "reset password" flow
3. Send a password reset link to the user

This enables me to create the users and allow them to set their own password, without having to send them the initial password. I would like to follow the same flow for the user creation through Apps Script, if possible.

However, in the [documentation for the Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#update_user), it seems like I can only reset the password and force the user to reset it on their next login, but there is no way to send the same password reset email I can send through the G Suite Admin UI.

Is there a way to do this programmatically? If not through Apps Script, maybe there is a different way?

For reference, this is the functionality I am refering to (after the actual password reset):

[image: Reset password screen]

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60029628/admin-sdk-generate-link-to-access-reset-password-page).

Comment: So far all that I found is that you can reset the password with user.update and then email that password using gmail api

Comment: Isn't sending an email with the password in plaintext a little bit risky ?

Comment: @Paulloed exactly - that's why it would be nice to be able to trigger the password reset email programmatically (which includes a passwort reset link, but no password)